# operators in c# for Func<in T, bool>

Tags: c#, operators

I need to compare two instance, which are in same type.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name { get;set;}

    public static bool operator < (Person p1, Person p2)
    {
         return p1.Age < p2.Age; 
    }
    public static bool operator > (Person p1, Person p2)
    {
         return p1.Age > p2.Age;
    }
}
```

Now in Main i have the code:

```
Person o = new Person()
{
    Age = 10,
    Name = "Matin"
};
Func<Person, bool> test = person => person < o;
Person o2 = new Person()
{
    Age = 9,
    Name = "hehe"
};

Console.WriteLine(test(o2));
```

**output: true;**
and in my opinion, the 1st person is greater than the second. Could you explain me this situation?

Comment: That is exactly what your code says - The first person is greater than the second ? your func is testing if the current person (o2) is smaller than the first person (o). So you are getting the exact response.

Comment: @KamilT test is Func (lambda)

Comment: `o` is in the second position, so it is correct. You want `p => o < p`

Comment: You need *1th person is greater than second*, Output says *2nd is lesser than o(1st)*. Both are same.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
Func<Person, bool> test = person => person < o;
```

So you are passing the person and comparing it with the first one (`o`).

```
test(o2)
```

transforms to the

```
evaluate `o2 < o`
```

which is true, as `o2.Age < o.Age` (9 < 10).

Answer (score 2):

You should implement IComparable like this:

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        return this.Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Person o = new Person()
{
    Age = 10,
    Name = "Matin"
};
Person o2 = new Person()
{
    Age = 9,
    Name = "hehe"
}

Console.WriteLine(o.CompareTo(o2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test is:

> The person passed to the function must be less than `o`

In this case, "less than" means "has a lower age than".

Then you pass in `o2`, so let's see:

- `o2`, age 9
- `o`, age 10

So yes, `o2` is less than `o`.

Output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In the call to `test(o2)`, the object `o2` is passed to `test` as parameter `person`.
In this way, the expression `o2 < o` is evaluated, which yields `true`, since the Age of `o2` is 9, and the Age of `o` is 10.

Answer (score 1):

The output is true because is exactly that your code says.

to do a good comparation you need two variables (at the moment, you are using all the time "o" instance to compare)

Do `Func<Person, Person, bool> test = (person1, person2) => person1 < person2;`

and then `Console.WriteLine(test(o, o2));`